# Inconsistent JSON output when serializing enums in Rust

Tags: rust, serde

I'm using `serde_json` to serialize an enum to JSON.
This is what I'm getting when serializing `std::net::IpAddr`:

```
use std::net::IpAddr;

fn main() {
    let addr : IpAddr = "127.0.0.1".parse().unwrap();
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&addr).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}
```

output:

```
"127.0.0.1"
```

However, when I write my own similar enum and serialize it, it looks different:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
    One(String),
    Two(String),
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::One("one".to_string());
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}
```

output:

```
{"One":"one"}
```

Why does the first snippet write a JSON string while the second one writes a JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `impl Serialize for IpAddr` isn't derived but [written like this](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/src/serde/ser/impls.rs.html#722-743):

> ```rust
> impl Serialize for net::IpAddr {
>     fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
>     where
>         S: Serializer,
>     {
>         if serializer.is_human_readable() {
>             match *self {
>                 net::IpAddr::V4(ref a) => a.serialize(serializer),
>                 net::IpAddr::V6(ref a) => a.serialize(serializer),
>             }
>         } else {
>             match *self {
>                 net::IpAddr::V4(ref a) => {
>                     serializer.serialize_newtype_variant("IpAddr", 0, "V4", a)
>                 }
>                 net::IpAddr::V6(ref a) => {
>                     serializer.serialize_newtype_variant("IpAddr", 1, "V6", a)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Note especially the `is_human_readable()` branch where it just delegates to the `Serialize` implementations of the respective inner types and doesn't add anything for the variant.

Comment: ah, I was looking for this but my brain told me I should be looking around IpAddr implementation not serde

Comment: Well `std` can't really use the downstream crates to implement their traits, so it's really up to the crates that define a trait to implement it for anything applicable in `std`